# undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

[The different repository images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89BfL.png)

```
add_executable(test_labyrinthe test_labyrinthe.cpp)
add_test(test_labyrinthe.cpp test_labyrinthe)
target_link_libraries(test_labyrinthe ${GTEST_LIBRARIES})
```

This is what I have in Test/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(TP1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    Labyrinthe.cpp
    Labyrinthe.h
    Piece.cpp
    Piece.h
    Porte.cpp
    Porte.h
    Principal.cpp)

add_executable(TP1 ${SOURCE_FILES})


###########
## GTEST ##
###########

option(BUILD_TESTING "build unit tests" ON)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  include(ExternalProject)

  ExternalProject_add(gtest-target
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/google/googletest"
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extern"
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  )

  include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extern/include)
  link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/extern/lib)
  set(GTEST_LIBRARIES pthread gtest gmock gtest_main gmock_main)

  enable_testing()

  add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

This is what I have in the main `CMakeLists.txt`. Keep in mind that I have the only line `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` in `test_labyrinthe.cpp`.

When I run `cmake ..` and `make`, I got

```
[ 53%] Built target gtest-target
[ 86%] Built target TP1
Scanning dependencies of target test_labyrinthe
[ 93%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/test_labyrinthe.dir/test_labyrinthe.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable test_labyrinthe
/usr/bin/ld: /home/infinity/ULaval/Session_Hiver_2021/Algorithmes_et_Structures_de_donnees/Travaux_Pratiques/TP1/CodeTP1/extern/lib/libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o): in function `main':
gtest_main.cc:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/infinity/ULaval/Session_Hiver_2021/Algorithmes_et_Structures_de_donnees/Travaux_Pratiques/TP1/CodeTP1/extern/lib/libgtest_main.a(gtest_main.cc.o): in function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
gtest_main.cc:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0x9): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()'
/usr/bin/ld: gtest_main.cc:(.text._Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv[_Z13RUN_ALL_TESTSv]+0x11): undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test_labyrinthe.dir/build.make:84: test/test_labyrinthe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:152: test/CMakeFiles/test_labyrinthe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:95: all] Error 2
```

This is really weird. Not sure how to make this work. Can you help?

**EDIT** When I run `make test`, I got

```
└╼ make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/infinity/ULaval/Session_Hiver_2021/Algorithmes_et_Structures_de_donnees/Travaux_Pratiques/TP1/CodeTP1
    Start 1: test_labyrinthe.cpp
Could not find executable test_labyrinthe
Looked in the following places:
test_labyrinthe
test_labyrinthe
Release/test_labyrinthe
Release/test_labyrinthe
Debug/test_labyrinthe
Debug/test_labyrinthe
MinSizeRel/test_labyrinthe
MinSizeRel/test_labyrinthe
RelWithDebInfo/test_labyrinthe
RelWithDebInfo/test_labyrinthe
Deployment/test_labyrinthe
Deployment/test_labyrinthe
Development/test_labyrinthe
Development/test_labyrinthe
Unable to find executable: test_labyrinthe
1/1 Test #1: test_labyrinthe.cpp ..............***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.00 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - test_labyrinthe.cpp (Not Run)
Errors while running CTest
make: *** [Makefile:84: test] Error 8
```

Comment: The library `gtest_main` uses functions from `gtest`. Because of that, `gtest_main` should come **before** `gtest` in the linker command line. But your order is opposite: `set(GTEST_LIBRARIES pthread gtest gmock gtest_main gmock_main)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried, but it doesn't seem to help. Still have the same problem. I have using VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the underlying problem is:

> Keep in mind that I have the only line `#include <gtest/gtest.h>` in `test_labyrinthe.cpp`.

You'll want to add an actual test case to the file.

`test_labyrinthe.cpp`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(SomeTest, ABasicTest) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}
```

Once you do that you'll probably run into some pthread linker errors.  Changing to link pthread after gtest should resolve that.

`set(GTEST_LIBRARIES gtest gmock gtest_main gmock_main pthread)`

Answer (score -1):

After uncountable tries, the solution was to add `-pthread` as you see here:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")`